# How can I use SharedPreferences in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I Downloaded the plugin from http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/preferences/

Copied `AppPrefrences.js` to `/js folder`,

passed `$cordovaPreferences` in my `AppCtrl`

but getting error:

> Unknown provider: $cordovaPreferencesProvider <- $cordovaPreferences

How to implement Cordova preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install and include ngCordova as well

http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/

#### Get the Source File

You can use bower to install ngCordova like so or download the zip file here, and locate the .js file in the dist folder:

```
$ bower install ngCordova
```

Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file (since ngCordova depends on AngularJS).

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

#### Inject as an Angular dependency

Then, include ngCordova as a dependency in your angular module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```